# How putting a "search posts" box also in the page that lists the users? (/wp-admin/users.php)?

Tags: post, search, admin, box

I have in the this page /wp-admin/edit.php a search posts box modified by code, I can with it also filtering by post ID. Now I'd like the have this specific search posts box in the user admin table (/wp-admin/users.php) for my internal business purposes. Any idea about how doing it?

This is the code that "empower" my default "search posts" box

```
//cerca per ID
add_filter('posts_where', 'posts_where');
    function posts_where($where)
        {

            $s = $_GET['s'];

            if(!empty($s))
            {
              if(is_numeric($s))
              {
                global $wpdb;

                $where = str_replace('(' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', '(' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $s . ') OR (' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', $where);
              }
              elseif(preg_match("/^(\d+)(,\s*\d+)*\$/", $s)) // string of post IDs
              {
                global $wpdb;

                $where = str_replace('(' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', '(' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID in (' . $s . ')) OR (' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_title LIKE', $where);
              }
            }


          return $where;
        }
```

I need to filter by post ID also from the page /wp-admin/users.php